# PySpark Structured Streaming - Watermark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am learning Spark Structured Streaming using Python from Spark website. While implementing Watermark concept on streaming data, i am not getting expected output.
In Batch 2, I am not supposed to get rows 2 & 7 and should get only row 7 as i am using update mode. Can someone clarify why this happened?

Here is the code:-

```
# Start Streaming
from pyspark.sql.functions import window

streamingData = spark\
            .readStream\
            .schema(fileDF.schema)\
            .option('maxFilesPerTrigger', 1)\
            .option('header', True)\
            .format('com.databricks.spark.csv')\                  
.load('/PySpark/Files/Source/Streaming/watermark*.csv')

windowedCounts = streamingData \
            .withWatermark("timestamp", "10 minutes") \
            .groupBy(
                window(streamingData.timestamp, "10 minutes", "5 minutes"),
                streamingData.name) \
            .count()

# Write Stream
windowedCounts\
 .writeStream\
 .format('memory')\
 .queryName('watermark_stream')\
 .outputMode('update')\
 .start()
```

**Run 1:**

Input:

timestamp,name

2018-07-19 13:27:00,dog

2018-07-19 13:28:00,owl

Output:

0  (2018-07-19 13:20:00, 2018-07-19 13:30:00)  dog      1

1  (2018-07-19 13:20:00, 2018-07-19 13:30:00)  owl      1

2  (2018-07-19 13:25:00, 2018-07-19 13:35:00)  dog      1

3  (2018-07-19 13:25:00, 2018-07-19 13:35:00)  owl      1

**Run 2:**

Input:

2018-07-19 13:34:00,dog

2018-07-19 13:29:00,cat

Output:

0  (2018-07-19 13:20:00, 2018-07-19 13:30:00)  dog      1

1  (2018-07-19 13:20:00, 2018-07-19 13:30:00)  owl      1

2  (2018-07-19 13:25:00, 2018-07-19 13:35:00)  dog      1

3  (2018-07-19 13:25:00, 2018-07-19 13:35:00)  owl      1

4  (2018-07-19 13:30:00, 2018-07-19 13:40:00)  dog      1

5  (2018-07-19 13:25:00, 2018-07-19 13:35:00)  cat      1

6  (2018-07-19 13:20:00, 2018-07-19 13:30:00)  cat      1

7  (2018-07-19 13:25:00, 2018-07-19 13:35:00)  dog      2

Comment: How did you fixed this?